# Outlook ItemAdd event not work constantly

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I have a tiny C# program which listen to the outlook with ItemAdd event, every time I start the program, it will malfunction after a few days run, for example I start the program on Monday, it will be failure on Thursday, or Wednesday, then it has to be restarted.
What's going on behind the scene? And how to fix it?

This should not be RAM issue? Because I have 32G RAM.
Win10 21H1, Outlook 2016, .net framework 4.7.2

=========================================

Problem solved, I give up the COM-way handling and adopt MailKit, things are getting straight and clear.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private NameSpace _ns;
    private readonly ApplicationClass _outlook = new ApplicationClass();
    private readonly StringProcessor _processor = new StringProcessor();
    private Items _items;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Main();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            _ns = _outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder myFolder;

            if (Environment.UserName == XmlService.UserName)
            {
                var box = XmlService.Inbox;
                myFolder = GetFolderItem(box);
            }
            else
            {
                myFolder = _ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            }

            if (myFolder != null)
            {
                _items = myFolder.Items;
                _items.ItemAdd += Items_ItemAdd;
            }
            else
            {
                Loger.PrintLog("Can not get folder");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Loger.PrintLog(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Items_ItemAdd(object item)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any Error message?

Comment: Nope, it just run on backgroud silently, I wanted to have some monitor on it, but I don't know how.

Comment: have a look at the event viewer of Windows.

Comment: found nothing useful..

Comment: Your Logger doesnt tell you anything either?

Comment: Yeah, it's quite clean. Is there any posibility that the object was killed by something?

Comment: how about that try/catch of the Form2_Load ? that is just swallowing any exceptions

Comment: Oh there's something in that try/catch, I deleted it because sensitive info, it also log error messages but nothing useful in that log.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that folder based events in Outlook were only designed for the UI purposes. The events can be dropped under heavy loads; they can also be disconnected if there was an RPC failure, especially in the online (as opposed to cached) mode.

The events should at best be a hint that you code that processes new events needs to run sooner rather than later.

Comment: So this is not the ideal way to monitor the mailbox? Is there any approach other than using com-interop?

Comment: You poll periodically, reset the event handler every once in a while, or switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) which supports Incremental Change Synchronization API (the same API used by Outlook to sync its OST file)

Answer (score 0):

> it will mulfunction after a few days run

Most probably the Outlook process was closed automatically. Try to create an Outlook window by using the [Explorers.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorers.add) or [Inspectors.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.add) method which creates a new instance of the explorer or inspector window and keep them alive in the code like you do for the `Items` collection. Note, without calling the `Display` method any Outlook UI will not be visible.

Comment: The Outlook didn't close, it was just receiving mails on the taskbar silently, I could still see new mails in. So did my tiny program, except that it can not invoke the event, or it did invoke but the codes not worked.